# How to search exact product title with ServiceExecute

Tags: searching, query, serviceexecute

I am trying to find the exact product title having phrase "HEPA filter bags" on "amazon.com" but it doesn't return the correct result.

```
ServiceExecute["GoogleCustomSearch", "Search", {"Query" -> 
   "HEPA filter bags", "Site" -> "https://www.amazon.com", 
  MaxItems -> 5, "SearchType" -> "Web"}]
```

The output/result of the search are (sorry I don't know how to copy from Mathematica to paste here, thus I have to convert to picture and upload):

[image: output/result from the code]

I want to get/show only products having the exact title "HEPA filter bags" like the product in the last line of the Title column . The first 4 products/links should be throw away from the output.

Could you please advice me how to fix the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: This requires a google account, an API key, and agreeing to the GoogleCustomSearch service terms of use. If it doesn't _return the correct result_ then you should show that bad result in the question otherwise it's unlikely anyone will guess what the problem is.

Comment: @flinty thank you for your comment. I have google account and have updated the results. Please check and advise. Thank you