# How to extract detail subsection of Metadata

Tags: export, string-manipulation, metadata

I am trying to get subsection of the Metadata such as image, title, url, title, description but it is impossible. Can you advise how to get this information from the follow code and results.

```
out = ServiceExecute["GoogleCustomSearch", "Search", {"Query" -> "HEPA filter bags", "Site" -> "https://www.amazon.com", MaxItems -> 1, "SearchType" -> "Web"}]
```

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please paste the details of `out` instead of asking readers to execute the search. The question is about info extraction, not the search.

Comment: @Syed: detail of out has 4 columns, the last column is Metadata having 5 subsections: image, title, url, title, description.

Comment: @Syed: thank you for your comment. It is special out type. I can't paste as text because the content is disappeared. When I paste/upload as picture, the content is available. Thus I have update the out as picture.

Comment: @Syed Thank you. I try with out[[1, 4]] and First@out[[1, 4]] but can't separate the Metadata. When I copy and paste result here, I get only : Dataset[ <> ]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130987/discussion-between-anh-and-syed).

Comment: I will let someone knowledgeable about datasets help you. Try: `out["Properties"]` and see what the dataset contains and update your post/delete intermediate comments.

Comment: @Syed Thank you for your kind. My real problem is https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257436/how-to-search-exact-product-title-with-serviceexecute and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257411/how-to-use-webexecute-to-check-the-checkbox-and-to-select-the-item-in-dropdown-l. Please let me know someone can solve this. Thank you